# Collapsing toolbar not visible

Tags: android, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I don't know whats happening but when i load data in first fragment and scroll down the toolbar collapses as expected but when i scroll up the toolbar appears but no content is visible(Image 1) and when i switch tab the nit appears as it should (Image 2)

Image 1
[image: Image 1]

Image 2 
[image]

and here's the code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TransparentText"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|enterAlways">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/image_view_pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="top|bottom"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                app:contentScrim="@color/primary"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:title="Glimray"
                android:titleTextColor="@color/dark_tone"
                />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/dark_tone"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary"
            app:tabMode="fixed" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: still couldn't find any solution...some1 help me plzz